# SseEmitter: connection closed after first event

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

after an update to Spring Boot 3 a I have a problem with SseEmitter.

The connection is closed after I use Thread.sleep()

Example code:

```
@GetMapping("/stream-sse-mvc")
fun streamSseMvc(): SseEmitter? {
    val emitter = SseEmitter(600_000L)
    val sseMvcExecutor: ExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    sseMvcExecutor.execute {
        try {
            for (i in 0..3) {
                emitter.send("message$i")
                Thread.sleep(500)
            }

            var i = 0
            while (i < 20) {
                val event = SseEmitter.event()
                    .data("SSE MVC - " + LocalTime.now().toString())
                    .id(i.toString())
                    .name("sse event - mvc").reconnectTime(500)
                emitter.send(event)

                Thread.sleep(500)
                i++
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            throw ex
            //emitter.completeWithError(ex)
        }
    }
    return emitter
}
```

Output:

```
Connection closed

14:13:55

message0

14:13:55

Connected to http://localhost:3000/tf/api/v1/tests/stream-sse-mvc
```

Do you know what I do wrong?

I need to have an opened connection and get all messages from BE code using Thread.sleep().

Thank you guys for any advice! :)